# Changing HTML button tag background color with css?

Tags: html, css, button

I am using the HTML button tag  for my submit buttons as well as buttons that direct to other pages and features I would like to be able to  have buttons with different backgrounds (one blue, one grey, one red, one green, etc) but can't seem to get it working by simply adding a class tot he button tag.

Here is what I have so far
**HTML**

```
<button class="green_btn" type="submit" name="cnp">News Control</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 134px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url('../images/darkgrey_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grey_btn button {
    background: url('../images/darkgrey_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
.green_btn button  {
    background: url('../images/green_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
.ltblue_btn button {
    background: url('../images/ltblue_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
.blue_btn button {
    background: url('../images/blue_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
.red_btn button {
    background: url('../images/red_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
```

by default I want the button to be the garkgrey_btn_bg.png as the background, but if I want to use the green_btn_bg.png for the background, adding class="green_btn" to the html does nothing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Note: I have tried putting the .green_btn after the button in the css, has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're targeting your class improperly with `.class-name button`. That is actually looking for an element with a child button.

Here you go...

```
button.grey_btn {
    background: url('../images/darkgrey_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
button.green_btn  {
    background: url('../images/green_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
button.ltblue_btn {
    background: url('../images/ltblue_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
button.blue_btn {
    background: url('../images/blue_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
button.red_btn {
    background: url('../images/red_btn_bg.png') no-repeat left;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried removing the 'button' completely from the class in the css and this also worked. I will use your method and see if that works as well (to keep it defined as a button). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your classes are looking for a button *inside* an element with a colour class. For example:

```
.red_btn button
```

...is looking for a button inside a parent element with the class `red_btn`. It should in fact be:

```
button.red_btn
```

...though the `button` part of the selector is probably redundant unless you have other elements of different types with the same class names.

Comment: I had done it this way originally, however my error was in having a space between button and .red_btn, breaking the whole thing, lol. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that ends up here who, like me, wasn't sure how to change a button's background color...

Instead of this in your CSS file:

```
#footer_join_button {
  background-color: $light_green; 
}
```

... or even:

```
#footer_join_button {
  color: $light_green; 
}
```

... the correct attribute/property to target is simply `background`:

```
#footer_join_button {
  background: $light_green; 
}
```

Note: I'm using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) precompiler, hence the potentially strange-looking `$light_green` variable above.